# How to filter locations on website by distance between

Tags: php

I Have test website where is listed restaurants with their gps coordinates. I want to make filter and display only items which are near my location. can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, I see your a member for at least 6 months, so I guess you've read the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) at least once.. We are NOT a free coding service...

Comment: i know that you aren't free coding service... i only want to know if there is any tool to help me with this problem, i don't want someone to give me ready code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you know your gps coordinates then

```
function distance(myloc, restloc) {
    x_dist = myloc.x - restloc.x;
    y_dist = myloc.y - restloc.y;
    return sqrt(x_dist*x_dist + y_dist*y_dist);
```

You can then filter by distance.